# Can't use $HOME in launchd.plist

Tags: macos, launchd

I want to run a shell script at startup. So I have used `launchd`.

Everything works fine if the path to the script is absolute like `/Users/mac/shell.sh`. But it gives error code `127` when  I provide the path like `$HOME/shell.sh` or `~/shell.sh`.

I have tried using `EnableGlobbing` key and `-c` as mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751321/how-to-access-environment-variables-in-launchd-plist). But still im getting error code `127` in `/var/log/System.log`.

My plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>mac.scriptd</string>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <true/>
    <key>EnableGlobbing</key>
    <true/>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/sh</string>
        <string>~/shell.sh</string>

    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```